# How to fix 'error in the metadata manager dimension id of missing ' error in SSAS?

Tags: deployment, metadata, ssas, dimension

I have this error that keeps popping up from time to time, the error is along the lines of the following:

Error -1055653635 : Errors in the metadata manager. The dimension with ID of <>, Name of <> referenced by the <> cube, does not exist.
Error -1055653859 : Errors in the metadata manager. An error occurred when loading the Blah cube, from the file, '\?\W:\OLAP\Data\BlahBlah Cubes.0.db\Blah.8.cub.xml'.

For starters the dimension it thinks is missing DOES exist in the SSAS database on the server. The dimension ids appear to match in both the cube and the dimension so its not like the ID's have been renamed and now they don't match. It can sometimes be fixed by effectively deleting the two cubes that use the same dimension, and then if you redeploy one of them the first one might re-deploy OK but not the second one. The puzzling bit is why the error keeps *recurring* when it has been previously resolved by deleting the database and starting again..etc. Is there some particular way we are using that dimension that is more likely to lead to the metadata manager getting confused (?)

Comment: Is W: drive local or a network share?

Comment: Good question! Im trying to work that out at the moment

Comment: Look in Server Manager / Storage / Disk Management.  If W: is not listed, it's not local and would be a risky choice for SSAS database storage.

Comment: Its on the analysis services database server. Surely the analysis services database should not be local? At any rate that folder contains a whole lot of files for each dimension (*.dim.xml files) and each cube (*.cub.xml). The cub file contains a reference to a dimension id and there does seem to be a dim file that relates to that dimension..but then again I don't quite get the way these files are organised to know whether there is an issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  It turns out that there were empty XML files in the directory it was complaining about.

This was my error specifically:

*Errors in the metadata manager.  An error occurred when instantiating a metadata object from the file, \?\R:\ANALYSIS\Warehouse.0.db\Role.5.role.xml*

When I navigated to \?\R:\ANALYSIS\Warehouse.0.db\ I discovered that the Role.5.role.xml file was 0KB.  I deleted (well moved, to be safe) the file, redeployed the solution and the error was gone :)

Comment: Easy way is deleting files. but firs we should stop SSAS service then delete file

Answer (score 0):

I would move your SSAS Database location to a local drive. From MSDN: "Any UNC path to a network share or any high latency remote storage solution leads to an unsupported installation."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280587.aspx

Comment: The server is on a SAN - does this count as unsupported?

Comment: I have but what's the difference between a UNC path to a SAN and a UNC path to a network share? It's on a SAN but the address looks similar to a path to a network share..

Comment: The difference as I understand it is that during the high-IO SSAS Process operation, any latency with the disk storage has a risk of causing those metadata errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the root cause but i recreated same error every time i process the cube.

Let me begin the story, I was working on optimization of cubes as our reports where running slow. I found out that there is a Customer dimension which is actually larger than fact "**Depreciated Dimension**", so i created new customer dimension "**customer1**" which has customers equal to fact. So that way, i **resolved** my **optimization**. Then there were 4 more cubes for which i have to create whole new customer dimension specific to those cubes. So i created second customer dimension "**customer2**" for another cube, thought of processing it first and boom, i got this error "**metadata manager error: \somelocation...\\customer1.dim.0.xml error**". I very carefully read that error message and i thought, why its throwing error for the dimension "**customer1**" when i am trying to process dimension "**customer2**". then processed dimension "**customer1**"  and it got processed. Then i processed my second dimension "**customer2**" and it got processed.

I was delighted but also pissed and confused, that how come this are interrelated or from which MS SSAS document says that u have to follow sequence for processing. So to test this i created 1 more dimension "**customer3**" then repeated same steps above. try to process first this dimension, got error , then processed the first dimension "**customer1**", then processed dimension "**customer3**" and again i got error but for dimension "**customer2**" then i processed dimension "**customer2**" then "**customer3**" all processed successfully. and now every time i have **to process**, i have to **follow sequences**. hope this helps..

Regards,

Avi

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. Go to Attribute Relationships tab on the Dimension and delete the problematic relationship.
Then you can create it again.

Comment: This answer is a stub and should rather be a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment. If you don't have enough reputation, read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) on how to contribute if you don't have enough reputation yet. Short answers like this may be considered low quality.